# WSO2 IS 5.5 - Are there rest APIs available for calling admin services?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

We recently upgraded WSO2 IS from 5.3 to 5.5. As per the WSO2 IS documentation, it says "From 5.4.0 onwards, the functionality provided by these SOAP APIs are provided through REST APIs. We recommend using REST APIs instead." 
But i could not find the rest URLs for calling the AdminServices .
Hereis the URL that i am referring to:
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/SOAP+APIs

Can anyone help me in finding out the rest APIs for the SOAP services - "RemoteUserStoreManagerService" and "UserIdentityManagementAdminService" please?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation you have pointed seems be little bit misleading.

The topic "Calling Admin Services" does not explain about a particular API. Instead it explains how to invoke a SOAP service in the Identity Server in general.

Next, each of the topic in the list does not have a exactly matching REST endpoints. For an example RemoteUserStoreManagerService SOAP API can be used for user management operations. For this you can use [SCIM 2.0 REST APIs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/SCIM+2.0+REST+APIs).

Can you explain the use case you are trying to achieve with UserIdentityManagementAdminService, so that I can help you with finding the correct REST endpoint for it.

Comment: Apologies for late reply, but to answer your question, we are using UserIdentityManagementAdminService for the admin relates operations like - Setting challenge questions, getting challenge questions of a user, etc.,